# Make background image fade in and continually move left

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have this neat [jQuery slider](http://www.slidorion.com/) going, and I want to have the image slowly slide from right to left as it fades in.

In looking at the jQuery I see this:

```
switch(effect){
    case 'fade':
    $new.css({'z-index':zPos,'top':'0','left':'0','display':'none'}).fadeIn(speed);
```

Now I'd like to get the image to continually slide left as it fades in until the next image appears.

```
$new.animate({
    left: parseInt($new.css('left'),10) == 0 ?
    -$new.outerWidth() :
    0
});
```

If I append this to the fade, the image slides left only after the duration of the slide plus the duration of the carousel. In other words, right before the image switches, it slides left. Also, I want to control the speed since the transition should be very slow.

How can I make the image continually slide left as if it were a non-stop fluid motion?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using [GreenSock (GSAP) v12](http://www.greensock.com/v12/) for animated effects. Use the timelineMax feature to que up multiple animations and play them at the same time instead of one after another.  It is way more flexible then jquery's animates and fades.  It lets you have complete control and worked great with jquery.

Comment: This is great, except I like the jQuery slider. Are you aware of how to start the animation with GS Tweening and then yield to the next jQuery command in the slider?